# Having trouble bubble sorting an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to bubble sort an array list and i keep getting an error `bad operand types for binary operator '>'` I am trying to sort it in numeric order for the test scores listed below. I am very new to java and am very confused on what to do. I am pretty sure integers are stored in the list.

My code is:

```
 public static void sort(){
               int k = 0;
           boolean exchangeMade = true;
           while((k < classroom.size() - 1) &&exchangeMade){
              exchangeMade = false;
              k++;
              for (int j = 0; j < classroom.size() - k; j++)
                  if(classroom.get(j) > classroom.get(j+1)){
                    swap(j, j+1);
                    swap(classroom, j, j+1);
                    exchangeMade = true;
              }
          }
```

The Rest of the code for the program is

```
public class Test {

  private static FileInputStream inFile;
  private static InputStreamReader inReader;
  private static BufferedReader reader;

  private static List<Student> classroom =
      new ArrayList<Student>(); // ArrayList to store the classroom.

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    initFile();
    getData();
    System.out.print(classroom); //output of the complete class.
    sort();
    System.out.print(classroom); //output after sorting.
    inFile.close();
  }

  // preparing the file for input

  public static void initFile() throws IOException {

    inFile =
        new FileInputStream(
            "C:\\Users\\clamanna\\Google Drive\\Senior\\AP COMP SCI\\!!VHSJava\\!!APCSDATA\\truefalse.txt");
    inReader = new InputStreamReader(inFile);
    reader = new BufferedReader(inReader);
  }

  //  Separate the id from the answers and store the answers in an array.

  public static void getData() throws IOException {
    String line = reader.readLine(); //Seed

    String[] answerkey = new String[10]; //Store the answer key from the first line of the txt file.

    for (int i = 0;
        i < answerkey.length;
        i++) { // take that line and place each answer in an array.

      answerkey[i] = line.substring(i, i + 1);
    }

    line = reader.readLine(); // read the following line of the txt file.

    while (line != null) // Read and create a student for each line.
    {
      String[] answers = new String[10];
      StringTokenizer strTkn = new StringTokenizer(line);
      String id = strTkn.nextToken();
      String answerline = strTkn.nextToken();

      for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {

        answers[i] = answerline.substring(i, i + 1);
      }

      Student stu = new Student(id, answers);

      stu.grade(answerkey, answers);

      classroom.add(stu);

      line = reader.readLine(); //updating what is being read
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the elements in `classroom`? This won't work unless they are a numeric type like `Integer`, `Float`, `Double` etc - and even then, you should be using `classroom.get(j).compareTo(classroom.get(j + 1)) > 1`.

Comment: where is implementation of swap method?

Comment: Does `Student` implement `Comparable<Student>`?

Comment: `Student` did not implement `Comparable<Student> ` I got a `cannot find symbol` error

Comment: Cannot find which symbol?

Comment: method `compareTo`

Answer (score 6):

Relational operators like `>` and `<` are only defined for numerical primitive types like `int` and `double`.

You can also use them for the equivalent boxed types like `Integer` and `Double`, because these can be auto-unboxed to the primitives.

To compare objects, you should use the `Comparable.compareTo` method:

```
classroom.get(j).compareTo(classroom.get(j+1)) > 1
```

Note that this requires your elements to implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface - which common types like `Integer`, `Double` etc do, as well as things like `String` (which implements it consistently with lexicographic order).

---

If your element class does not implement `Comparable` (and you can't make change it to implement it), you can use an "external" form of `Comparable` called [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), which is an interface like this:

```
interface Comparable<T> {
  int compare(T a, T b);
}
```

which you *don't* add to the class that you're wanting to compare - you implement this interface as a separate class so that `compare` returns a negative number, zero or positive number if you consider `a < b`, `a == b` and `a > b` respectively.

Then, you'd use:

```
comparator.compare(classroom.get(j), classroom.get(j + 1)) > 1
```

where `comparator` is an instance of a class implementing `Comparator<Student>`. (Actually, it can be `Comparator<? super Student>`, but let's not worry about that too much for now).